# ffmpeg encode audio multi thread

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to convert a video file that have h264 ready video track , and DTS audio track .

I run cmd attempt : copy the video track and convert DTS to AAC , but when check activity monitor , number of threads used by ffmpeg only 1 , although i set threads param to 4

```
ffmpeg -i titanic.mkv -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -c:v:0 copy -c:a:0 libfaac -threads 4 titanic.m4v
```

how can i make ffmpeg to utilize all my machine core , so it can use many thread as possible to increase conversion speed, when convert audio track only.

Thank and regard

Comment: I think the implementation of libfaac codec in ffmpeg does not support multithreading

Comment: What happens when you move the -threads option to the front? Such as ``ffmpeg -i titanic.mkv -threads 4 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -c:v:0 copy -c:a:0 libfaac  titanic.m4v``

Yes, this does matter.

Comment: @GeorgeY. it not work , the audio encode seem only use 1 thread only ..

Comment: Then libfaac really does not support multithreading as indicated above.

Comment: could you please guide me any solution to encode aac (video copy) that support multi thread